# Как привязать визуальный элемент загрузчика к ожиданию ответа от сервера?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Есть такой скрипт:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Home/Search',
    data: PS_Storage_Object.GetSearchInputs(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        PS_Parser_Object.SetData(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Произошел сбой ");
    }
});
```

Как сделать так что бы пока идет обработка запроса сервером на экране был подобный визуальный элемент загрузчика, а когда данные бы загрузились он бы исчезал?

[image: loading]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
loader.show(); // Включаем
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Home/Search',
    data: PS_Storage_Object.GetSearchInputs(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        PS_Parser_Object.SetData(data);
        loader.hide(); // Выключаем
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Произошел сбой ");
        loader.hide(); // Выключаем
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

в событии `beforeSend` (происходит непосредственно перед отправкой запроса на сервер.) запускать анимацию (например показать через `show`), а в конце `success` и/или `error` - убирать анимацию (например делать элементу `hide`)